# Change Audio and Video Bitrate of .mpg file to .mp4 file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have following command which creates me a .mp4 file from an .mpg file.

```
> ffmpeg -i video.mpg -minrate 1400k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k
> -deinterlace -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high -trellis 2 -crf 20 -acodec mp3 -ab 1400k -r 25 -s 1024x576
> video.mp4;
```

I need to have a bitrate of

> 1400 kbps

for the video part and a bitrate of

> 192 kps

for the audio part.

Currently the windows "detail-explorer-window" gives me following information of that .mp4 I created:

```
Video
___________________________

Datarate      : 1338kBit/s
Totalbitrate  : 1660kBits/s


Audio
___________________________

Bitrate : 322 kBits/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -deinterlace -r 25 -s 1024x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p
       -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high
       -b:v 1350k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k -trellis 2 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr
       -acodec mp3 -ab 192k video.mp4
```

Added a nominal video bitrate, which is a touch lower, to reduce possible bitrate overshoot.

Comment: Hi thanks so I can't precisly get the bitrates I need?

Comment: With the above command, you should.

Comment: The windows explorer details show something different: `Video Data Rate: 1265` and `Audio Bitrate 193` is there any other good way to check this specs I somehow do not trust the window details explorer page

Comment: The program Power-Dvd tells me that the Audio Bitrate is correct but the video bitrate has `1.37Mbits`, the VLC player tells me that the Audio bitrate is correct but it does not show the video bitrate

Comment: 1400k bits = 1400 * 1000 bits = 1.367 * 1024 ~= 1.37 mbits